# How to access variable from the method inside the class in Python?

Tags: python, class

I have a database module in Python which connects to the database, extract the data from the table login. The extract data i.e username and password is hold by the variable uname and passw inside method inside the class. I am trying to that database module in login.py and I am gonna need the variable uname and passw. How can I access the variable? 
Here's the database.py.

```
#usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb as mdb


class data:
    hey = "ok"
    def __init__(self):
        """Retrieves the data from the database"""

    def db(self):   
        #Database Connection
        con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'devil', 'data');


        #Submit statements to SQL server
        cursor = con.cursor()       
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM login")

        #Retrieves data from SQL
        rows = cursor.fetchall()  
        row = list(rows)
        self.uname = [x[1] for x in row]
        self.passw = [k[2] for k in row]    

hello = data()
```

I want to call the variable uname and passw in login.py. How can I do that?

Comment: Why are you storing unhashed passwords in a database?

Comment: How do I make it hashed?

Comment: Do you use this database to authenticate users and check if their passwords are correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  Those variables are local to the method and don't exist except when the method is executing.  If you want to read those values later, you need to make them instance attributes by doing `self.uname = ...` and `self.passw = ...` instead.  Then you can read them later on from anywhere where you have a reference to the object.

Answer (score 2):

In your example `uname` and `passw` are local variable that are not visible outside `data.db()`. To make it visible you can make them instance attributes (fields) by adding `self.`. In constuctor you can add `self.uname = None` and in `db()` method `self.uname = [...]`.Then you can access them by `uname = hello.uname`.

If you want to use it in other file:

```
import database

db_data = database.data()
print('user: %s' % (db_data.uname))
```

Comment: Hello Michael, I have edited my code and called the uname variable by doing hello.uname in the same file but I got that same error! What I am doing wrong?